# PHP how to use where in to replace left join in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table, `records` and `common_member`.

`records` just store a plugin data. (Not frequently queried) but `common_member` was a huge data table and frequently queried.

Sample data of `common_member`

```
+--------+-----------+
| uid    | username  |
+--------+-----------+
| 1      | admin     |
| 2      | test1     |
+--------------------+
```

Sample data of `records`

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| uid    | amount    |createtime |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      | 50        |1234567    |
| 1      | 100       |5555555    |
| 2      | 2000      |9999999    |
+--------------------------------+
```

Normally I am using `$lrecord = mysqli_fetch_all("SELECT t1.*,t2.username FROM records t1 LEFT JOIN common_member t2 ON (t1.uid = t2.uid) ORDER BY t1.createtime")`.

But after that I was be informed if using `leftjoin` connect with `common_member`, It will be very inefficient and there was a way just using `where in` the get the `username` from `common_member`.

So, how to get the `username` from `common_member` without using `leftjoin`?

I want the final result of `records` array to be: (Means `username` from `common_member` join to `records`)

```
+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| uid  | username    | amount    | createtime|
+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1    | admin       | 50        | 1234567   |
| 1    | admin       | 100       | 5555555   |
| 2    | test1       | 2000      | 9999999   |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

My question is, how to use `where in` get the username in `common_member` without `leftjoin` ?

Thank you.

Comment: see this diagram

https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_HsHikmChBI/VmQGJjLKgyI/AAAAAAAAEPw/JaLnV0bsbEo/s1600/sql%2Bjoins%2Bguide%2Band%2Bsyntax.jpg

Comment: Your code is confusing. Just explain what you are trying to get from these two tables (or only one table ) in plain english.

Comment: @dodzb I did, but since I dont want using join, just want `fetch` the username from common_member first, and insert the username array into `records` while `records.uid = common_member.uid` ..

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Hi I has been edit, hope can understand what I means, thank you.

Comment: `WHERE t1.uid IN ([list-of-pre-fetched-ids])`

Comment: @Justinas `WHERE t1.uid IN (1,1,2);` but after `print_r` , only have 2 array `Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => admin ) [1] => Array ( [username] => test1 ) )` NOT `Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => admin )  [1] => Array ( [username] => admin ) [2] => Array ( [username] => test1 ) )` ..

Comment: You were misinformed

Comment: @SweeHong Create the following indexes `(createtime)` on `records` table; and `uid` on `common_member` table (you most likely have the second index as Primary Key). And use `LIMIT` clause in your query to restrict data to (let's say) 30 rows, and you should be good to go. You don't need to avoid `LEFT JOIN`. Infact, using `WHERE IN(...)` is going to be much more inefficient (especially in MySQL) than using `LEFT JOIN` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
But after that I was be informed...
```

(with respect...) who informed you ? phpMyAdmin ? another interface ? your friend ? a blog.. ?

there is no problem with the left join, but you must check the indexes of your tables.
It is necessary that in **both tables**, there is an **index** (preferably **primary**) on the **field uid**.
Otherwise, the request will not be optimized and can be slow.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question, `how to use where in get the username in common_member without leftjoin ?`, is that you can't.

The `where` clause is used for filtering results, not to add information to them. This could be usefull if you just want to retrive all rows in `records` which have an existing user. However, if database was *properly* designed, such a question wouldn't be asked, because `records.uid` would be an non-nullable foreign key referencing `common_member.uid`.

Hence, it wouldn't be necessary to make a `left join`, but only a `join`.

But, supposing this isn't your case, and the database isn't properly designed, and `records.uid` isn't a foreign key, then

```sql
select *
from records
where uid in (
   select uid
   from common_member
)
```

would return all records of existing users. But still, no username.

The only solution is to execute a join, as you are already doing:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,t2.username 
FROM records t1 
JOIN common_member t2 ON (t1.uid = t2.uid) 
ORDER BY t1.createtime
```